# Update one Wordpress SQL Table Based on Information from Another

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am trying to run an SQL command on a Wordpress database. I want to update certain entries in wp_6_posts table's `post-status` column with the value `"trash"`. The entries I want to update are the ones in table `wp_6_term_relationships` where the `term_taxonomy_id = 13`.

Then, for all those matches, I want to take the `object_id from wp_6_term` relationships and match it to the `ID` column in `wp_6_posts`.

Then I want to update only the `wp_6_posts` rows where the `ID` value matches the `object_id` value from the `wp_6_terms_relationships` table.

This is the closest I've come, but it just sets the `post_status` value of ALL posts in `wp_6_posts` to `"trash"`. I know I just have the syntax or a bit of logic off.

```
UPDATE wp_6_posts   
SET post_status = "trash"
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT object_id
    FROM wp_6_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id = "13"
    AND object_id = ID
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE wp_6_posts   
SET post_status = "trash"
WHERE id IN
  ( SELECT object_id
    FROM wp_6_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id = "13"
  )
```

Comment: That works! Thanks so much. Now the only problem is that it seems some posts, all in the same category, and with only 1 wordpress category ID, are using different term_taxonomy_id's for some reason. Here we go again...

Comment: @Alan: You mean you want to update all with `WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN ("13", "21", "34", "55")` instaed of only those with `13` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that works for me, given to me by someone better at SQL. This query is using the category slug instead of the category ID #. I don't understand it fully, but it works--it gives all posts in category "sold" the post_status of "trash".

```
update wp_posts set post_status = 'trash'
where `id` in
(SELECT object_id
FROM wp_term_relationships wtr
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON ( wtr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id ) 
JOIN wp_terms wt ON ( wtt.term_id = wt.term_id ) 
WHERE wtt.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wt.slug = 'sold')
```